# BigQuery table load from Cloud Storage not working in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-bigquery

I'm loading data from a CSV located in Cloud Storage from a simple NodeJS script without problems, using RunJS:

```
  const bucketName = 'xxxx';
  const filename = 'datasets/soa/soa.csv';
  const datasetId = 'lbl';
  const tableId = 'soa';
  const metadata = { ... }

  const [job] = await bigqueryClient
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), metadata);

  console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);
```

Everything works fine. But when I implement the same code in my backend project using Typescript, it always raises the error:

**Source must be a File object.**

I tried everything I know. This is my Typescript code:

```
import { BigQuery } from "@google-cloud/bigquery";
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";

loadData() {
  const bucketName = 'xxxx';
  const filename = 'datasets/soa/soa.csv';
  const datasetId = 'lbl';
  const tableId = 'soa';
  const metadata = { ... }

  return this.client
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId)
      .load(this.storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), metadata);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. It's a webpack issue. Webpack is renaming all classnames, so I used TerserPlugin this way:

```
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
  // context: __dirname,
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          keep_classnames: true,
          keep_fnames: true
        }
      })
    ]
  },
...
```

Now all class names are not renamed and is working perfectly.